# The right way of showing images on UITableView?

Tags: ios, uitableview, uiimage, tablecell

I am developing an app, that takes events from 3 different shared calendars, and show them, sorted by date, in a UITableView.
first calendar is for "Sports Shown on TV"
second calendar is for "Live Music on Stage"
third calendar is for fixed events (like every thursday is "ladies night")

I would like to show a small image on the cell, and the image needs to change according to the event. The way I do it now is to just write the image filename in the event description, and use that to set the image.

```
cell.imageView.image = [UIImage imageNamed:[entry valueForKeyPath:@"content.$t"]];
```

What i would like to do was to set the image according to either the calendar name, or maybe the contents of the event title

I tried

```
NSArray *gdWho = entry[@"gd$who"];
NSString *calendar = gdWho[0][@"valueString"];
if([calendar isEqualToString:@"Live Music on Stage"])
{
    cell.imageView.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"music-notes-40x40.jpg"];
}
```

and it works, but as soon as i scroll the tables they get mixed up. I read somewhere that this is an expected outcome, as the cells indexpath change when scrolling, thus rendering my code unusable.

But how would you do it then. Could anyone point me in the right direction - I would really like to able to put an image of the artist playing live on stage, so my optimal solution would be to display an image if the NSString = `[entry valueForKeyPath:@"title.$t"]` contained for example the name "dennis"

Comment: Where did you read that the indexpath changes? The indexpath will always be the right one for the given cell and if that ever was inconsistent then nothing would work.

Comment: Wherever you're getting the description and other event data, you should also be getting the image type.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> it works, but as soon as i scroll the tables they get mixed up

This indicates a problem with `UITableViewCell` "recycling". You need to change the code of your `tableview:cellforrowatindexpath:` in such a way that it sets `cell.imageView.image` unconditionally, not only when the cell is created for the first time.

In addition, you could replace the chain of `if` statements that check the `calendar` for various specific values with a lookup in a dictionary, like this:

```
// This code goes into your viewDidLoad method. imageForCalendarType is an ivar
imageForCalendarType = @{
    @"Live Music on Stage" : [UIImage imageNamed:@"music-notes-40x40.jpg"]
,   @"Sports Shown on TV"  : [UIImage imageNamed:@"sport-tv-40x40.jpg"]
,   @"Fixed Event"         : [UIImage imageNamed:@"fixed-40x40.jpg"]
};
```

Now you can use the image from the dictionary, like this:

```
// This goes into your tableview:cellforrowatindexpath: method
cell.imageView.image = imageForCalendarType[calendar];
```

Comment: Wow - that works perfect.
One question:
The Fixed Events calendar contains 4 different events:
Ladies Night
Student Night
St Patricks Day
Monday Jam

is it possible to change the imageForCalendarType Dictionary, to sort between these? Or do I have to add an if statement in the `CellForRowAtIndexPath`method again?

Comment: I am already displaying the title of the event on the cell like this:

`NSDictionary *entry = sectionEntries[index][indexPath.row];
cell.textLabel.text = [entry valueForKeyPath:@"title.$t"];`

Comment: @catu You can make the lookup key for `@"Fixed Event"` picture a two-part key (e.g. `@"Fixed Event-Ladies Night"`, `@"Fixed Event-Student Night"`, etc.). Then add a condition for when the `calendar` is `@"Fixed Event"`, make a composite key for look up in the `imageForCalendarType`, e.g. with `[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@-%@", calendar, subtypeName]`.